# How can I emulate Unicode input without actually typing the letters?

Tags: luatex, unicode, expansion

I admit, this is an unusual question, most people want to do the opposite. However, I frequently make use of older tools that don't always play nice with Unicode, so it's nice to just have pure ASCII instead of fiddling with getting unicode to work. For reference, here's my MWE (compiled with LuaLaTex):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\setmonofont{Latin Modern Mono Prop}

\UndeclareUTFcomposite{x0233}{\=}{y}


\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\UrlSpecials{\do\ȳ{\=y}}
\makeatother

\usepackage[backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8,useprefix,mincrossrefs=1]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{testbib.bib}
    @online {mysite,
        author = "John Doe",
        date = "2016-01-01",
        url = "http://www.\=y.com/",
        organization = "My Website",
    }
\end{filecontents}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=url]
      \step[fieldset=verba, origfieldval]
    }
  }
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\mkbibacro{URL}\addcolon\space\url{\thefield{verba}}}

\addbibresource{testbib.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{mysite}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Note: the `\DeclareSourcemap` and `\DeclareFieldFormat` commands are there to prevent the URL from being converted to URI-escaping, we can ignore that.

The problem is the command `\g@addto@macro\UrlSpecials{\do\ȳ{\=y}}`. Now, obviously, this is a rather trivial example, but I want to figure out if this is possible for future reference. What I'd like, is something like this:

```
\newcommand{\ym}{\char"0233} % U+0233 is the codepoint for ȳ

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\UrlSpecials{\expandafter\do\csname \ym\endcsname{\=y}}
\makeatother
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't work. Any idea on how I could get what I want to work? Is such a thing even possible?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Hmm, I'm not sure if that's correct. For example, ``\do\Y{\=y}`` causes any inserted uppercase Y (for example, ``http://www.Y.com``) to behave like ``\=y``.

Comment: `\Uchar`, perhaps?

Comment: Well, so what happens, I think, is that ``\=y`` gets converted to ``ȳ`` when read in by Biber/BibLaTeX. However, ȳ doesn't exist in my mono font, so I did ``\UndeclareUTFcomposite`` command so that fontspec won't look for the character in the font, and instead compose it.

Comment: @JosephWright how would I use that? I'm not familiar with that command

Comment: I don't think that you can use `\UrlSpecials` with command names, you need to use `\do\ <some character> `. Beside this I find it quite suspicious that biber replace the \=y in the url. I would have thought that it leaves verbatim material alone ...

Comment: @JosephWright `\^^^^0233` works as well

Comment: I added an issue to the biber issue tracker regarding the handling of commands like \=y in verbatim fields: https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/141

Comment: Please try biblatex 3.7 and biber 2.7 in development on Sourceforge - this should be fixed now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can *always* type in a Unicode character in the range `x0`–`xFFFF` as

```
^^^^xyzw
```

where `xyzw` are four hexadecimal *lowercase* digits. For characters above `x10000` one has to use `^^^^^^xyzuvw`, with six hexadecimal digits. So character U+0233 can be expressed as `^^^^0233` and U+FFFF as `^^^^ffff`.

Actually, characters in the range `x0`–`xFF` can also be expressed as `^^xy` as in Knuth TeX. The important thing is that `^` has category code 7 (which it usually has in the document preamble).

In your case

```
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\UrlSpecials{\expandafter\do\^^^^0233{\=y}}
\makeatother
```

will do.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Joseph Wright's suggestion, I found a solution using the `\Uchar` command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\setmonofont{Latin Modern Mono Prop}

\UndeclareUTFcomposite{x0233}{\=}{y}


\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\UrlSpecials{\expandafter\do\csname \Uchar"0233\endcsname{\=y}}
\makeatother



\usepackage[backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8,useprefix,mincrossrefs=1]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}


\begin{filecontents}{testbib.bib}
    @online {mysite,
        author = "John Doe",
        date = "2016-01-01",
        url = "http://www.\=y.com/",
        organization = "My Website",
    }
\end{filecontents}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=url]
      \step[fieldset=verba, origfieldval]
    }
  }
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\mkbibacro{URL}\addcolon\space\url{\thefield{verba}}}


\addbibresource{testbib.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{mysite}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\do\^^^^0233{\=y}` is simpler